# How to enforce Type Members Layout setting in ReSharper?

Tags: c#, coding-style, resharper

In Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Type Members Layout it is possible to set up a custom layout of members in types.

This is all very cool, but is there a way for ReSharper to display a warning if the layout is mismatched? It could work exactly the same way as with all other Resharper-detected violations - a yellow bar could be displayed in the scrollbar and I would immediately know something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only thing you can do right now is run Code Cleanup on your code files (either as a batch or one at a time). If you have your settings correct, this will fix any out-of-order members.

If you just want to receive a warning but not actually fix the issues, however, I think you are out of luck (at least as of version 7.1.3).

Answer (score 1):

If you use StyleCop with ReSharper, ReSharper will underline the warning/error from StyleCop. It says to me that the order isn't right.